# Access reverse proxyed services in DMZ from LAN

Tags: reverse-proxy

In my environment I have a few web services that are exposed to the internet with an nginx reverse proxy. Moreover, for some of these nginx does a port translation (es. internal 8080 -> public 80).
We also have a few of internal services that from LAN need to contact the reverse proxyed ones: what is the best practice to accomplish this? Here is what I thought:

- Create a fake DNS zone in our internal DNS, so if an internal services contacts publicservice1.example.com is redirected directly to nginx DMZ IP
- Do not touch anything, but the traffic loops out and in our network (LAN-> Internet (public IP) -> nginx reverse proxy in DMZ )

Answer (score 1):

It's subjective but barring any new information, I will make the following recommendation:

Let the LAN clients hit the public IP and route back into the DMZ. It is simpler, Clearer and more consistent for end users.

You won't have to explain why a cached DNS entry from the office is blocking access from home. You won't have to worry about the split horizon synchronization and keeping the records in each updated.

---

If you have other reasons for deploying split horizon and you have other systems configured in this manner, then keep things as consistent as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Gathering more informations about this topic I found that the LAN->Internet->DMZ loop is called "NAT reflection" or "NAT loopback", and this answer [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282094) guided me to a correct configuration.